# How do I add an array to an array OR unpack a dynamically generated array in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, powershell, outlook

My Function spits out an array for each email in my inbox. I want to either add them to a list to unpack, or dynamically unpack them to use the values as strings in a SQL query.

I've written my function and verified it is returning arrays as I expect and experimented with |s ForEach-Object, ForEach, and more.

As it is in PowerShell the function is:

```
Function Get-OutlookInBox
{
    Add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
    $olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders” -as [type]
    $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
    $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
    $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)
    #Is an array now I just need to break down this array into constituent parts so i can DB these hoes.
    return $message = $folder.items | Select-Object -Property SenderName, Subject, SentOn, ReceivedTime, BCC.
}
```

This function returns a bunch of arrays which represent emails and their properties that I would like to either:

1. Immediately unpack so I can put them into a database
2. Pack into an array and add to an array/list to pass off to a function that would unpack and check/insert into a database.

The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to put the arrays my function is spitting out into an array to unpack or unpack the arrays as they are spit out so that I can insert them into a table.

If I were trying to do this pythonically it would look something like:

```
listOfEmailes = list()
for x in GetOutlookEmails():
    listOfEmails.appened(x)

for email in listOfEmails:
    sender =  emails[0]
    Sent = emails[1]
    received = emails[2]
    BCCs = emails[3]
# Craft SQL string here with substitution
sqlquery = blah
# Execute crafted SQL query here.
dosql(sqlquery)
```

My thought is if I were to do something like

```
$EmailProperties = @{}
$Inbox = Get-OutLookInbox

ForEach ($message in $Inbox)
{
     $EmailProperties.add($Message)
}
```

and the resultant array would look something like:

```
@{ @{array1}, @{array2}, @{array3}, etc...}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code looks like it should be returning individual messages, not an array of messages. the `$Inbox` variable would have an array of msgs because it caught all the individual msgs from your function.

Comment: @mklement0 You can put `[mcve]` in a comment, which will automagically be expanded to [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, @AnsgarWiechers, that's handy. I happen to have a custom `mcve` "hotstring" that expands to what I used in my comment, and I figure it can't hurt to show the initialism "MCVE" too, given that readers are likely to encounter it repeatedly. To other readers: [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) shows all supported so-called shorthand links (`[...]`) that can be used in comments.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey See that's the thing. Ive been thinking my code should add the array of email properties  to the array and return it but it doesn't appear to be doing soand it seems that I'm probalby improperly using @{} but I'm not sure how/where

Comment: @user502301 - i misunderstood this `return $message = $folder.items |`. i suspect that if you remove the `return $message = ` and just leave the rest of the line, you will get the individual items sent out as each exits the pipeline. i would likely use a `foreach` loop and explicitly put each item on a line alone to send it out, tho.

Comment: Two asides: (a) You should call `$outlook.Quit()` in your function to properly release the Outlook COM object. (b) `return $message = ` is unnecessary in two ways: you're instantly returning, so the local variable `$message`  is useless; `return` is only ever necessary if you need to explicitly exit the function; here it is the last statement anyway and not needed; without `return $message = `, the output from `$folder.Items | ...` would _implicitly_ be returned (output).

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: While removing `return $message = ` makes sense due to being superfluous, it won't change the behavior: either way you get object-by-object output to the pipeline; try `& { return $a = 1..3 } | % { $_; sleep 1 }`

Comment: @mklement0 - that is not what i would expect. [*frown*] this ` return $message = ` should put all the pipeline output into the variable and THEN send out the content of the variable as a whole. ///// i confess that i have not tried it ... [*blush*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Yes, it is somewhat counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be working with large arrays, consider using `System.Collections.Generic.List`. Adding to normal arrays has the side effect of copying the array which can lead to an unnecessary use of memory. Using your psueudocode as a prop here):

```
$Inbox = Get-OutLookInbox
$EmailProperties = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Hashtable]( $Inbox.count )

ForEach ( $message in $Inbox )
{
    $EmailProperties.add(@{
      PropertyOne = $message.SomeProp
      PropertyTwo = $message.SomeOtherProp
      AnyColourYouLike = $message.DarkSideOfTheMoon
      IThinkYouGetIt = $message.HeGetsIt
    })
}
```

If you prefer `PSCustomObject` instead of a hashtable, change the List type to `PSCustomObject` and cast the `Hashtable` to one by changing the first line with the `.add` call above:

```
$EmailProperties.add([PSCustomObject]@{
```

That said, it's unclear what you're trying to do here based on your question. You are already returning an array, are you actually trying to add *hashtables* to an array instead? If I'm off base, please clarify your question.

EDIT: I changed this a bit assuming you want a `HashTable` of properties from the email object.

EDIT 2: Added how to make this work as an array of `PSCustomObject` if desired.

Comment: I'm trying to get a set of properties from each email, make them an array/list, and then create an array/list of arrays/lists to return to a calling function that will unpack and process each array  however it needs to be done. It seems like I'm inadvertently creating a hash table instead of a list but I'm not 100% sure what to do to correct this problem. I'm new to powershell and already thought I was creating lists.

Comment: Arrays and lists are similar, but they are different. [Here is a short summary of the differences between the two in .NET](https://csharp-station.com/c-arrays-vs-lists/)

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why you need an array of arrays of email properties. Why not just one array of email properties, where each index is a `Hashtable` (or a `PSCustomObject` if you take @mklement0's advice) of properties of that email?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Get-OutlookInBox` function outputs ***custom objects*** (`[pscustomobject]` instances) containing select properties of email messages, which is what `Select-Object` outputs.

You can **think of `[pscustomobject]` instances as "property bags"** similar to, but distinct from hashtables; they act **just like other objects whose properties you can access directly by *name***.

By assigning the result to `$Inbox` the latter will contain an array `[object[]]` of such `[pscustomobject]` instances if *2 or more* objects are output, and a single `[pscustomobject]` instance otherwise.

By type-constraining the receiving variable to `[array]` you can ensure that you're *alway* getting an array:

```
# Cast [array] ensures that $Inbox is always an array, even with just 1 output object.
[array] $InboxMessages = Get-OutlookInBox
```

You can then iterate over the custom objects and access their properties:

```
foreach ($message in $InboxMessages) { # loop over all messages
  $sender = $message.Sender    # access the .Sender property
  # ...
}
```

Of course, you can cut out the middleman and use the pipeline to directly iterate over your messages:

```
Get-OutlookInBox | ForEach-Object { 
  $sender = $_.Sender    # access the .Sender property; $_ is the input object at hand.
  # ...
}
```